# Browser extension popup navigation?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-addons

How are you supposed to handle navigation within an extension popup?

I tried to make a button that when clicked calls a function that sets `window.location.href` to `newpage.html`, but it does nothing.

I know there's a `browser.browserAction.setPopup` function, but going off the description of it that only seems applicable for setting the first page when opening the extension, and not for navigation.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Same problem though.

Comment: It means there's some other problem in the code because `location.href` is the correct method.